# Using a method from a derived WCF proxy class (VS 2010 generated) yields error

Tags: c#, .net, magento

I am trying to interface the API WebService which Magento (os commerce solution) provides.

Since this webservice from magento needs a session handling for each method (apart from `login` and `endSession`), I want to wrap the generated WCF proxy class inside my own class, doing all the session handling stuff.

However, I cannot for my life figure out why my derived class works differently than the original WCF wrapper from which I derive. Especially long running methods fail (with this stack trace:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Internal Error. Please see log for details.
Server stack trace:
    bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
    bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

This is (the first draft) of my wrapper class (with MagentoService being the generated Proxy class to the Magento Webservice:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace MagentoConnector
{
  public class MagentoController : MagentoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient
  {
    private string username = "apiusername";
    private string password = "apiuserpassword";
    private string sessionId = null;
    public MagentoController(string url) : base()
    {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) {
        if(!url.ToLower().StartsWith("http://")) url = "http://" + url;
        if(!url.EndsWith("/")) url += "/";
        url += "magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/";
        this.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url), this.Endpoint.Address.Identity, this.Endpoint.Address.Headers);
      }
      this.Open();
    }
    public MagentoController(string url, string username, string password) : this(url)
    {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) {
        this.username = username;
      }
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
        this.password = password;
      }
      sessionId = this.login(this.username, this.password);
    }
    public new string login(string username, string password) 
    {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) {
        this.endSession(sessionId);
      }
      sessionId = base.login(username, password);
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      return sessionId;
    }
    public string login() 
    {
      return login(this.username, this.password);
    }
    public void logoff()
    {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) {
        this.endSession(sessionId);
      }
    }
    ~MagentoController()
    {
      try {
        logoff();
      } catch(Exception) {
        ;
      }
    }

    public MagentoService.catalogCategoryTree catalogCategoryTree(string parentId, string storeView)
    {
      return base.catalogCategoryTree(sessionId, parentId, storeView);
    }

    public static MagentoService.catalogCategoryTree getCatalogTree(string parentId, string storeView)
    {
      string sessionId = null;
      MagentoService.catalogCategoryTree myTree = null;
      MagentoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient myService = new MagentoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
      try {
        myService.Open();
        sessionId = myService.login("applus-dev", "FL1LBveiNW8nGOg9QRa4z");
        myTree = myService.catalogCategoryTree(sessionId, null, null);
      } finally {
        if(myService != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId)) {
          myService.endSession(sessionId);
        }
      }
      return myTree;
    }
  }
}
```

Do notice the static method `getCatalogTree`, this one directly interfaces with `MagentoService`, and works as it should (returning a tree of all category nodes of magento).
The method `catalogCategoryTree` fails upon calling the base method, with the error mentioned above.

Here is the calling code:

```
MagentoController myService = new MagentoController(null, null, null);
MagentoService.catalogCategoryTree myTree = myService.catalogCategoryTree(parentId, storeView);
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening. What is the difference between using the static method and the one which is calling the base class?

Apart from that, consuming the magento webservice is a pain in the a#* (getting better with the v2 soap service) with .NET...

Kind regards,

Arndt

Comment: Digging deeper I found out that this only happens on methods which take some time to process / send a lot of data.

But still I do not understand why this happens in my derived class when I call the methods of the base class, but not if I instantiate the base class directly, calling the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and its name is stupidity...

Magento does allow for empty parameter `parentId` in the `catalogCategoryTree`-method.

In order to test my wrapper class I built a simple form which passes on both `parentId` and `storeView` parameters to the `catalogCategoryTree-method. However, when nothing is entered I pass on empty string literals (the value of the text fields). Then the error occurs...

The working static test method I posted above discards both `parentId` and `storeView`-parameters and passes on `null` to the magento API, which magento oviously can handle. So, Magento differs between null parameters (for strings at least) and empty strings.

If I rewrite my own `catalogCategoryTree` method to check for empty strings everything works as planned...

```
public MagentoService.catalogCategoryTree catalogCategoryTree(string parentId, string storeView)
{
  parentId = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId)) ? null : parentId;
  storeView = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeView)) ? null : storeView;
  return base.catalogCategoryTree(sessionId, parentId, storeView);
}
```